# Is there a way to find which Tasks are running on the same DbContext causing errors?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am running into an error with EF Core where some of my calls are using the same dbContext and am getting an error that states something like "Error with Multiple Tasks Running Concurrently on Same DbContext" but due to the size of the codebase I am having a hard time telling what parts of the code are causing this error. Is there a good way to debug this type of error? I've tried looking for code that is not awaited, but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a good way to debug this type of error?

I don't know of an easy fix, no.

> I've tried looking for code that is not awaited, but to no avail.

This kind of error is usually caused by one of three things:

- Asynchronous code that is not awaited.
- Having an incorrect scope for DbContext instances, so that the Dependency Injection system ends up sharing instances when you don't expect.
- Code doing asynchronous concurrency, e.g., `Task.WhenAll`, when each concurrent task shares the same DbContext.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

That's why EF provides the `async` API, it synchronizes calls so they don't run at the same time as needed. Just replace every single non-`async` call with the `async` version and your problem will go away.

The answer to your specific question is, "all of them".

Comment: Thank you for your response